# How to add user to firebase database from rest api without login and password?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm making chat which will be based on firebase. 
The chat is gonna be part of our existing site which already has authentication and registration, and also users will not be able to create chat rooms or enter them,
it all will be handled by site automacally. Users only will be able to read and write messages to chat rooms to which they were previously added by site. 
For automatic authetification I think to use `signInWithCustomToken()` method.
But I don't quite understand how to automatically create users and add them to chat rooms. The `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` 
method needs email and password but I wanna just add users without any emails and passwords. I've read docs but could not find any solution, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and chose to use the email and password login and just created an email (username@myapp.com) and password each time I needed to add users

Comment: well, if there is no a better way to do will do it in it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom tokens and use them to authenticate. Sample java code

```
public static String createCustomToken(String userId, Map<String, Object> additionalClaims) {
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream(FIREBASE_ACCESS_FILE)).build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
Task<String> customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(userId, additionalClaims);
return customToken.getResult().toString();
}
enter code here
```

When the user logs-in to your website, you can return above generated custom token. The client app(ios,android or web) can use this custom token to sign-in as below

```
  firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
              // Handle Errors here.
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
              // [START_EXCLUDE]
              if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-custom-token') {
                alert('The token you provided is not valid.');
              } else {
                console.error(error);
              }
              // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
```

Comment: the thing is that I need to creatie users in firebase from api so I could add them to chats without them even knowing, so I will probably need uid or something for that.

Comment: yes, you can use the uid which you already have in your existing site and which you are using for authentication and registration